# stop at the last frame of the update "callback_args"

Tags: perl

still studying the "Term::Animation" library and would like your help.
I made a fixed loading bar, and another shape "shape" that disappears from from left to right. Since then I've been trying to brake the fixed loading yellow bar when it reaches the end. Because every time when it reaches the end, it restarts.
If I reset the `callback_args => [0,0,0,0],` the loading does not start.
is what keeps the frames up to date is the last digit `≠ 0`, which also implies speed.
can you give me a direction?
I've been searching for hours and I can't find any references.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# you don't have to include Curses, but it is handy so we
# can use halfdelay and getch below.
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;

# this creates a full screen animation object. you can also
# pass a curses window as an argument to new()
my $s = Term::Animation->new();

# if you are going to use color, you must enable it immediately
# after creating the animation object. you can turn color off
# again afterwards by calling disable_color()
$s->color(1);
 
my $phrase = "Press q to exit";

# a few simple ASCII art objects to move around

my @loading= (q{
=
},
q{
==
},
q{
===
},
q{
====
},
q{
=====
},
q{
======
});

$s->new_entity(
        # here we pass in an array of animation frames
        shape           => \@loading,
        position        => [ 30, 2, 20],
        # the last element of the vector represents the
        # animation frame. for each update, the loading bar will be
        # move forward one animation frame (and back
        # to the first frame when it reaches the last frame)
        callback_args   => [0,0,0,1],
        default_color   => 'YELLOW',
);

my $shape = q#
<=O=>
#; 
# turn our shape into an animation object
$s->new_entity(
             shape         => $shape,        # object shape
             position      => [3, 7, 10],    # row / column / depth
             callback_args => [1, 0, 0, 0],  # the default callback
                                             #  routine takes a list
                                             #  of x,y,z,frame deltas
             wrap          => 1              # turn screen wrap on
);

# halfdelay is a Curses call to tell getch  how long it should
# wait for input before it times out (in tenths of a second).
# you can use halfdelay and getch to control the frame rate
# of your animation, if you don't expect to be getting much
# input from the user. 
halfdelay( 2 );

# here is the main animation loop.
for(1..500) {

# run the callback routines for all the objects, and update
# the screen
$s->animate();

# ask for user input, and wait a bit. exit our loop
# if the user gives us a 'q'
my $in = lc( getch() );
if($in eq 'q') { last; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom callback and check the frame index before calling `move_entity()` :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# you don't have to include Curses, but it is handy so we
# can use halfdelay and getch below.
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;

# this creates a full screen animation object. you can also
# pass a curses window as an argument to new()
my $s = Term::Animation->new();

# if you are going to use color, you must enable it immediately
# after creating the animation object. you can turn color off
# again afterwards by calling disable_color()
$s->color(1);
 
my $phrase = "Press q to exit";

# a few simple ASCII art objects to move around

my @loading= (q{
=
},
q{
==
},
q{
===
},
q{
====
},
q{
=====
},
q{
======
});

my $max_frame  = $#loading;
my $loading_cb= sub {
    my ($entity, $animation) = @_;
    my $frame = $entity->frame();
    $entity->frame($frame-1) if $frame == $max_frame;
    return $entity->move_entity($animation);
};

$s->new_entity(
        # here we pass in an array of animation frames
        shape           => \@loading,
        position        => [ 30, 2, 20],
        # the last element of the vector represents the
        # animation frame. for each update, the loading bar will be
        # move forward one animation frame (and back
        # to the first frame when it reaches the last frame)
        callback_args   => [0,0,0,1],
        default_color   => 'YELLOW',
        callback => $loading_cb,
);

my $shape = q#
<=O=>
#; 
# turn our shape into an animation object
$s->new_entity(
             shape         => $shape,        # object shape
             position      => [3, 7, 10],    # row / column / depth
             callback_args => [1, 0, 0, 0],  # the default callback
                                             #  routine takes a list
                                             #  of x,y,z,frame deltas
             wrap          => 1              # turn screen wrap on
);

# halfdelay is a Curses call to tell getch  how long it should
# wait for input before it times out (in tenths of a second).
# you can use halfdelay and getch to control the frame rate
# of your animation, if you don't expect to be getting much
# input from the user. 
halfdelay( 2 );

# here is the main animation loop.
for(1..500) {

# run the callback routines for all the objects, and update
# the screen
$s->animate();

# ask for user input, and wait a bit. exit our loop
# if the user gives us a 'q'
my $in = lc( getch() );
if($in eq 'q') { last; }

}
```

This adjusts the frame index when the last entry is reached.
You could also modify callback_args instead:

```
my $max_frame  = $#loading;
my $loading_cb= sub {
    my ($entity, $animation) = @_;
    my $frame = $entity->frame();
    $entity->callback_args([0,0,0,0]) if $frame == $max_frame;
    return $entity->move_entity($animation);
};
```